# QGIS join attribute data to dxf file using EntityHandle as key field

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, attribute-joins, dxf, entityhandle

I would like to joint attribute data (csv table or slt.) to a drawing (dxf file) imported to QGIS.

Such imported data have an attribute `EntityHandle` which seem to me like an AutoCAD specific 'id'. I'm not an AutoCAD specialist, therefore the question:

Can it be ensured, that this 'EntityHandle' does never change (e.g. when changing the drawing in AutoCAD)? Is this a suitable way to join attribute tables and dxf's?